# LaTeX: Standard Errors (output below the line of maths)

Tags: math-mode

[image: Regression]

I'm trying to replicate the above, but am unsure how to deal with putting the standard errors in the line below. Any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using the `amsmath` package, you can use `\underset`:

```
\hat{p}_{t} = \underset{(1.958)}{0.900}+\underset{(0.017)}{0.997}p_{t-1},
```